# Gnome Tweaks icons and cursor doesn't change

Tags: desktop-icons, gnome-tweaks, cursor-theme

I installed a cute icon for my pc, but when I put the new icon/cursor it doesn't change.

All the options looks like feature ubuntu design. (My version of Ubuntu is 18.04)

[My gnome tweaks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbeCc.png)

I applied `alt+F2`and `r`. Nothing.

I change the directory from `/home/myuser/.icons` to `/usr/share/icons`. Nothing again.

[The directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xBr1m.png)

Comment: What is this "cute icon"? Is it an icon theme? How did you install it? How do you "put" it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reloading your desktop environment?

Press `Alt+F2` and type in `r`. Press `Enter`. I believe your cursor will change to what you installed.

Comment: this was the first thing that i try; but doesn't work for me: themes options work; only cursor and icon doesn't change :/

Comment: Okay. What theme did you get and which folder did you place everything into (as @vanadium said)? I can check into the files and see if there's anything wrong in there.

Comment: Themes that I installed are Candy icons and Oreo Cursors.

 First I saved on "/home/.icons". Later I used "usr/share/icons" and nothing happened.